# How can we log the passed/ failed url checks results in a console?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am grabbing all the url links from an HTML page and calling a function to send an XHR request for all the url links. I would like to console log for those passed and failed requests links in a proper way. I have got my result to some extent but not happy the way of console logs/errors. Can someone please advise where I need to correct console log ?

```html
<div id="WebLinks">
  <h2>All Links</h2>
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/">Link 1</a><br>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link 2</a><br>
  <a href="https://tellus.com">Link 3</a><br>
  <a href="https://loudop.com">Link 4</a><br>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Link 5</a><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="linkChecker" onclick="linkCheck();" value="linkChecker">
</div>
```

// How can I improve the console logs for passed and failed ones. Also remove some of console errors;

```
var linkCheck = function() {
  var arr = [],
    l = document.links;
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    arr.push(l[i].href);
    console.log(arr[i]);
    urlCheck(arr[i]);
  }

  function urlCheck(arr, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (callback) {
          callback(xhr.status < 400);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('HEAD', arr);
    xhr.send();
  }

  urlCheck(arr, function(exists) {
    console.log('"%s" exists?', arr, exists);
  });

}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/jtcyh753/34/)

Comment: Why not use `fetch` api instead? Not that it would change the idea, but it leads to much cleaner code if you don't need to support archaic browsers. Anyhow, you're passing an array of URLs to `urlCheck`, which expects a single URL. And the callback function does not print the status, only the URL.

Comment: Also you're not going to be able to load most pages from JS anyway because of cross origin restrictions. As expected, only the `jsfiddle` request succeeds.

Comment: Riv: I haven't used fetch api...I understood regarding the cross-origin restrictions, but it would be nice, if I can get 'true' in console for valid urls, here console.log('"%s" exists?', arr, exists);

Comment: Your `console.log` prints the URL, but not the `exists` flag - there is substitution rule for `exists?`, if that's what you expected. You can check the validity by using `mode: "no-cors"` option in `fetch` (not sure what the corresponding option with XMLHttpRequest is), which will successfully fetch the response, but it will contain opaque data that can't be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `fetch` API using `mode: "no-cors"` option:

```js
window.linkCheck = function() {
  function urlCheck(link) {
    fetch(link, {mode: "no-cors"}).then(
      () => console.log(`${link} is valid`),
      () => console.log(`${link} is invalid`)
    );
  }

  var arr = [],
    l = document.links;
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    arr.push(l[i].href);
    urlCheck(arr[i]);
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="WebLinks">
  <h2>All Links</h2>
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/">Link 1</a><br>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link 2</a><br>
  <a href="https://tellus.com">Link 3</a><br>
  <a href="https://loudop.com">Link 4</a><br>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Link 5</a><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="linkChecker" onclick="linkCheck();" value="linkChecker">
</div>
```